# gvariant parsing for a complex format

Tags: linux, gtk, glib, dbus

In my application i will be getting a message over dbus which has to be parsed using gvariant functions.

The format string is G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a(ysb((sss)(sss)))"

A sample code to construct a gVariant is as below

int ParseVariant (GVariant *value);

```
int main()
{

GVariantBuilder *builder;
GVariant *value;


builder = g_variant_builder_new (G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a(ysb((sss)(sss)))"));
g_variant_builder_add (builder, "(ysb((sss)(sss)))", 'J', "Test1", TRUE, "Hn", "di", "hedfs", "dd", "dr", "hdf");
g_variant_builder_add (builder, "(ysb((sss)(sss)))", 'J', "Test2", TRUE, "Hn", "di", "hedfs", "dd", "dr", "hdf");
//g_variant_builder_add (builder, "(ysb((sss)(sss)))", 'J', "Test3", TRUE, "Hn", "di", "hedfs", "dd", "dr", "hdf");


GVariant *result = g_variant_new ("((yu)ya(ysb((sss)(sss))))", 'R', 23, 'E', builder);

g_variant_builder_unref (builder);
ParseVariant (result);
}
```

Am looking for a parser function (ParseVariant (result)) using which I can extract each element of the variant result.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problems did you encounter? In short g_variant_get is what you need to use. https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-GVariant.html#g-variant-get. If you still have problems after trying that please post your specific questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer I provided on your question on the Gtk mailing list where you also supplied a `ParseVariant()`:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

int ParseVariant (GVariant *value)
{
    GVariant * list;
    gchar ch1,ch2,ch3;
    gchar *str1,*str2,*str3,*str4,*str5,*str6,*str7;
    gboolean bool1;
    gint x;
    GVariantIter iter;

    g_print ("Inside Parse\n");

    g_variant_get (value, "((yu)y@a(ysb((sss)(sss))))", &ch1, &x, &ch2, &list);
    g_variant_iter_init (&iter, list); 
    while (g_variant_iter_loop (&iter, "(ysb((sss)(sss)))", &ch3, &str1, &bool1, &str2, &str3, &str4, &str5, &str6, &str7))
    {
        g_print ("%s\n", str1);
    }
    g_variant_unref(list);
}

int main()
{
    GVariantBuilder * builder = g_variant_builder_new (G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a(ysb((sss)(sss)))"));
    g_variant_builder_add (builder, "(ysb((sss)(sss)))", 'J', "Test1", TRUE, "Hn", "di", "hedfs", "dd", "dr", "hdf");
    g_variant_builder_add (builder, "(ysb((sss)(sss)))", 'J', "Test2", TRUE, "Hn", "di", "hedfs", "dd", "dr", "hdf");

    GVariant * result = g_variant_new ("((yu)ya(ysb((sss)(sss))))", 'R', 23, 'E', builder);

    g_variant_builder_unref (builder);
    ParseVariant (result);
}
```